# How to get GhostScript.dll?

Tags: c#, .net, ghostscript

I'm downloading various versions of Ghostscript, but I can't find the DLL of it. Where can I get it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can download it here, if you dont want to navigate much:
http://www.dlldll.com/ghostscript.dll_download.html

Answer (score 2):

have you seen http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/, ghostscript home page?
download the binary, you'll find gsdll32.dll in %PROGRAM FILES%/gs/gs9.01/bin/